# How to store the soup in bs4 , Python memory usage

Tags: python, memory, beautifulsoup

For the past few days, I have been researching an efficient way to save the HTML content in BeautifulSoup (bs4) in a memory-efficient manner. Using the `sys` module, I checked the size of the HTML content as a string with the `sys.getsizeof()` method.

The string size was 1599140 bytes. However, when I used the string in `self.soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')`, the resulting BeautifulSoup object was only 48 bytes large, and `soup.soup` was 16 bytes.

This puzzled me because when I checked `len(soup.soup)`, the result was 1. But if I printed it, I got the entire HTML.

Did I do something wrong in my experiment, or is it indeed more memory-efficient to store the content with bs4? And if not, is there an efficient alternative?

Comment: `sys.getsizeof()` does not return the string size. It is the size in bytes of the Python object in memory not including the size of additional references. Use `len()` for string or container sizes in number of elements

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might be misunderstanding the way BeautifulSoup (bs4) works and how memory usage is calculated.

When you create a BeautifulSoup object using `BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')`, the resulting object is not just a representation of the HTML content as a string. Instead, it's a data structure that represents the HTML document in a way that makes it easy to navigate and manipulate.

Here's a breakdown of what you observed:

1. The original HTML content as a string had a size of 1599140 bytes.
2. The BeautifulSoup object itself is much smaller (48 bytes), as it's a Python object that stores references to the parsed HTML structure.
3. When you access the `soup.soup` attribute, you are likely seeing a string representation of the entire HTML document. The size of this string would be larger than the BeautifulSoup object itself because it includes the parsed HTML and might have additional formatting.

So, when you check the size using `sys.getsizeof()`, you are measuring the size of the Python object (BeautifulSoup) and not the size of the HTML content.

If your goal is to save memory, storing the original HTML content as a string is more memory-efficient than creating a BeautifulSoup object. However, if you need to work with the HTML structure and perform tasks like searching for elements, modifying the document, etc., then using BeautifulSoup is the recommended approach.

If you only need to extract specific information from the HTML and don't require the entire document's structure, you might also consider using regular expressions or other parsing techniques that are more lightweight than BeautifulSoup. However, keep in mind that using regular expressions to parse HTML is generally not recommended, as HTML is a complex language with nested structures that are better handled by a dedicated parser like BeautifulSoup.